# Is there an efficient way of sending a large raster image?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arccatalog, aerial-photography, ftp

Rather simple question: I have two large raster images that are stored in ArcSDE. I need to send these images to someone else, and post it on their ftp site. What is the most efficient way to send these rasters?

I tried creating a geodatabase and copying to images and pasting into the database, but that took forever. Is there a faster way?

Comment: How big are we talking?

Comment: 60GB, per raster

Comment: Are you trying to get them to someone on your network or over the web?

Comment: An outside contractor provided me with their ftp site

Comment: I think I would try direct uploading to their ftp through FileZilla.  https://filezilla-project.org/

Comment: Not sure what platform they are using, but you may want to export them out of the FGDB so they are just in their native format (.tif for example)

Comment: Either way you go, 120 GB is a lot of data for the web and will take a while, probably several hours depending on your upload speed.

Comment: Also,  you said that you created a geodatabase and copy pasted rasters into it?  Don't think that will work,  you would have to import the rasters into the geodatabase either through ArcMap or ArcCatalog.  Then send your contractor the FGDB.

Comment: Are you looking for the most efficient *transfer* or the most efficient *format*? Ideally you should be looking at both. Try to get the files as small as possible while still in a format readable by your customer (e.g. as tiled GeoTiff with lossless compression or maybe even take a look at JPEG2000). Depending on your connection you maybe also want to take a look at splitting the data up so you can have multiple upload threads and don't have to start over again should the connection reset during upload.

Comment: @Kersten Well, both. The client is looking for the raster, so I suppose it doesn't matter which format it is in, so long as its readable.

Comment: Further to Kersten's comment, also consider pixel depth and bands.  Can you reduce it to 8 or 16 bits if it is a 32 bit raster and can you reduce the number of bands or go from floating point to integer (it will depend on the data of course)?  Also, ECW is another format to consider for good compression as well as JPG2000.

Answer (score 4):

It's been most of a decade since storing rasters inside an ArcSDE-enabled database was best practice, but if your geodatabase is old enough (though not too old), there may be a simple solution:  The `sde2raster` and `raster2sde` utilities of [se_toolkit](ftp://ftp.esri.com/pub/staff/vangelo/se_toolkit/index.html) were written for exactly this purpose.

To export an image, use `sde2raster -o export` with the `split=...` option in the file parameter, as shown in the third example in the [documentation](ftp://ftp.esri.com/pub/staff/vangelo/se_toolkit/docs/se_raster/sde2raster.html) (though `nice` might not be needed):

```
$ sde2raster -o export -l world.gtopo_1km,raster \
        -f sample3.x00:split=100m:comp=gzip:stop=cancel.now

ArcSDE 10.2 Raster Export Tool           Tue Jan 26 23:42:08 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exporting table WORLD.GTOPO_1KM (3 columns)...

        Raster #1

  Image Envelope .......  URx:      180.000018,   URy:       90.000008
                          LLx:     -180.000001,   LLy:      -90.000001
  Image Size (WxH) .....: 43200 x 21600
  Pixel Type ...........: short (16-bit)
  Band Count ...........: 1 band

     Exporting image:
        20.0% complete -- 1.2 minutes remaining...
  Creating volume 'sample3.x01'...
        40.0% complete -- 57 seconds remaining...
  Creating volume 'sample3.x02'...
        80.0% complete -- 16 seconds remaining...
  Creating volume 'sample3.x03'...
         100% complete (01:15.4 elapsed)

  Export file 'sample3.x00' complete --
            Rows: 1
         Written: 323.45Mb (82.24% compression)
        Duration: 1.26 min
```

Importing the export image set is accomplished by `raster2sde -o create`, referencing the lead `.x00` file (first example in the [documentation](ftp://ftp.esri.com/pub/staff/vangelo/se_toolkit/docs/se_raster/raster2sde.html)):

```
$ raster2sde -o create -f sample3.x00 -l sample3clone,raster

ArcSDE 10.2 Raster Loading Tool          Tue Jan 26 23:48:54 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Raster #1

  Image Envelope .......  URx:      180.000018,   URy:       90.000008
                          LLx:     -180.000001,   LLy:      -90.000001
  Image Size (WxH) .....: 43200 x 21600
  Pixel Type ...........: short (16-bit)
  Band Count ...........: 1 band

    Inserting raster:
        20.0% complete -- 25 seconds remaining...
  Opening volume 'sample3.x01'...
  Opening volume 'sample3.x02'...
        80.0% complete -- 7 seconds remaining...
  Opening volume 'sample3.x03'...
         100% complete (00:33.2 elapsed)

create completed -- 1 row in 1.15 min
```

Because moving a large number of export volumes over a network link might involve errors, it would probably be wise to verify the volume set with the `rasterinfo` utility ([documentation](ftp://ftp.esri.com/pub/staff/vangelo/se_toolkit/docs/se_raster/rasterinfo.html)):

```
$ rasterinfo -o scan -f sample3.x00 -v

ArcSDE 10.2 Raster Description Tool      Wed Jan 27 01:22:43 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------

    File: sample3.x00
  Format: Export (x00)

        Table Layout

  Column                           Type       Null?    Rowid?
  -------------------------------- ---------- -------- --------
  oid                              INT32      NOT NULL SDE-set
  footprint                        SHAPE               
  raster                           RASTER              

        Vector Properties

      Spatial Column: footprint
         Description: (none)
             Keyword: RASTER
              EFlags: nac+Q
     Coordref Origin: -400.000,-400.000
      Coordref Scale: 11258999068426.199
   Coordinate System: Geographic (Degrees)
            Spheroid: WGS_1984

        Raster Properties

      Spatial Column: raster
         Description: Raster Column
             Keyword: RASTER
            GDB Type: NONE
   Coordinate System: Geographic (Degrees)
            Spheroid: WGS_1984

        Raster #1

  Image Format .........: ESRI_SDERASTERDATASET
  Image Envelope .......  URx:      180.000018,   URy:       90.000008
                          LLx:     -180.000001,   LLy:      -90.000001
  Image Origin .........  CCx:     -179.995834,   CCy:       89.995842
  Image Size (WxH) .....: 43200 x 21600
  Pixel Size (WxH) .....: 0.0083333338 x 0.0083333338
  Pixel Type ...........: short (16-bit)
  Band Count ...........: 1 band
  Pyramid Levels .......: AUTO
  Interpolation Model ..: NEAREST
  Colormap .............: NONE
  Transfer Size ........: 1.738Gb

    Skipping raster:
        20.0% complete -- 7 seconds remaining...
  Opening volume 'sample3.x01'...
  Opening volume 'sample3.x02'...
  Opening volume 'sample3.x03'...
         100% complete (00:08.9 elapsed)

scan complete -- 1 row in 8.89 secs
```

Both the sender and receiver would need to download the appropriate *se_toolkit* binaries, and possibly appropriate the command-line Admin installation (for the SDEHOME libraries).  The format is forgiving on release, especially if you use the binary associated with the exact version.

While this would address an immediate need, I strongly recommend you transition to a modern, more efficient raster handling implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the images to an external disk drive and send it via DHL.

Comment: While this is a viable solution it does in no way attempt to answer OPs question regarding sending it to a FTP.

Comment: How would that fit to 60GB onto DVD ? @David Doumeche

Comment: A external drive, not a dvd. Today drive can fit up to  2 or 3 To, and I guess the goal is more to get and use the Raster, than have it on a ftp.

Comment: @DavidDoumèche  Ok just making sure. Yes an External hard drive is the way to go. As long as it has the NFTS system in it it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this topic might help: [Transferring large raster datasets](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/transferring-large-raster-datasets.htm) where it describes breaking the a large raster image into **volumes** using the following command:

```
sdeexport –X option creates volumes
```

Although you may have to note the following passage (quoted from link) in terms of creating temporary storage:

> The **sdeexport** command requires a large amount of sort space to export raster data; therefore, you will need to create temporary space that is approximately 4 percent of the size of the final export file. If sderaster –o list –storage returns a total of 100 GB for the export file, you will need to have 4 GB of temporary space available.